# Transaction between SQL Azure and Azure Table Storage i.e Rollback and Commmit

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

At my current project we are working on a distributed cloud application that will store the state of an entity and the associated events. When a message is recieved from the queue we update the state of an entity in SQL Azure and save the events associated with that update in table storage.

It looks something like this:

Start UnitOfWork
Update Entity in SQL Azure
Save Events to table storage
Commit transaction
End UnitOfWork
The problem we are encountering here is that we can't submit the changes in SQL Azure and Table storage within one transaction. So when the saving of the entity in SQL Azure fails, we want to rollback the saving of the events in table storge.
Help is much appriciated.
I need to know any other mechanism availble for this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure Table Storage does not support distributed transactions. So the operations you perform in table storage won't be able to coordinate automatically with the operations you perform in SQL Azure. Yet, it is possible to do this coordination yourself.

Rolling back transactions in SQL Azure is straight-forward. You can control the transaction on the client such as by using a TransactionContext. Then you can commit or abort this transaction based on if the operations in table storage succeeded.

Rolling back transactions in table storage takes more thought if you are making multiple changes. There are many ways to achieve this. If you change multiple entities as part of your transaction you could have one top-level entity that you update last, and it points to the latest version of all the other entities. This way if something fails half way through, the top-level entity will still be pointing to the old version of the other entities. Then you need some clean-up mechanism to delete old entities that aren't used anymore.

Please keep in mind that just because a call to the table service failed, doesn't mean that entity wasn't updated. For example, the service might successfully process your request, but the response doesn't make it back to you because of some network error. So, if you're not sure if something succeeded, your code would have to verify it.

-Mike, Microsoft Windows Azure Storage Developer